# ReferenceError: Camera Is Not Defined

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to develop a `PhoneGap` application which uses the camera feature. I am following the plugin documentation at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/768, but with no luck. Everytime I try to use the feature I get the error "ReferenceError: Camera is not defined" when I build and test on my Android device.

Here is what the head of my index.html looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And here is the script I'm using to use the camera feature:

```
<script>
            function take_picture(){
                try{
                    navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
                        quality: 50,
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
                    });
                }catch(e){
                    alert(e);
                }
            }

            function cameraSuccess(imageData){
                try{
                    $("#camera_image").attr('src', imageData);
                }catch(e){
                    alert(e);
                }
            }

            function cameraError(message){
                try{
                alert('Failed because: '+message);
                }catch(e){
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
            </script>
```

And since I am using `PhoneGap Build`, here is the config.xml tags I am using:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <uses-permission name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</gap:config-file>

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>

<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Only use one or the other for `phonegap.js`/`cordova.js` not both. That may clear up the issue

Comment: Also, for phonegap build you don't need to add all of that to your `config.xml`, try removing what you have and add `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.2.9" />`

Comment: I took your advice, and made progress. Thanks for that. Now I'm getting the error "Failed Because: Camera Cancelled"

Comment: ok, done some more research and it turns out I had to change my launchmode value in AndroidManifest modification of my config.xml from "singleInstance" to "standard". That seems to correct the last issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem I solved it on three steps

#### The javascript include

I used cordova.js ONLY and removed any phonegap.js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

#### Installing the plugin(s)

You must install the camera plugin using command line; xml only doesn't work

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

#### Use right android-package

The package that you are using is `org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher` it is wrong and will give you  NullPointer exception.
The right package could be included like that

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

Give them a try!
Thanks :)

Comment: Now the most up to date version to download is ```cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera```